# solr on Bitnami Google cloud: cannot post data with the ADMIN/document page (permission denied)

Tags: solr, bitnami, google-cloud-console

I have a google cloud account and have bitnami:solr installed.

In the solr Admin console (after selecting the core: collection1) there is a page called 'Documents' that will index / upload data that is in the text box.

Using the default JSON data `{"id":"change.me","title":"change.me"}` on Submit, it gets an error that says:

> "msg": "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000028 (Permission denied)"

My Google account is the owner. Is this a Bitnami permission issue?
I also get the same error when trying to user post.jar and curl (I am sure the syntax is correct).

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami's developer here

I haven't been able to reproduce your issue on a fresh installation of Solr. I tested the version number 4.10.3-0 and 5.1.0-1 of Solr and I could submit data to the server.

Could you please tell us what version of Solr do you have? Did you modify the permissions of the installation's folders?

I suppose that you are using the 4 version of Solr and it seems that the folder doesn't have the correct permissions, could you please check it?

```
ls -la /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/collection1
```

Solr has to be the owner of that folder, if not, you can change the permissions using the next command.

```
sudo chown -R solr:solr /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/collection1
```

I could submit data using the following ways:

1. Using the Solr's admin console
2. Creating a json file with this text [{"id":"json","title":"change.me"}] and running the next command inside the exampledocs file

   sudo -u solr java -Durl="http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true" -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar example.json
3. Using curl

   curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"curl","title":"change.me"}]'

Jota